# Ordering bookmarks by page using microsoft interop c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, bookmarks

I have a template word file composed by 2 pages, each page has a bookmark, the first page bookmark name is A4 and the second page bookmark name is A3, but when I read all bookmarks from the word document I get them in alphabetical order, I want them in page order, how can i do this?

```
foreach (Bookmark bookMark in MergeResultDoc.Bookmarks) 
            {//IMPORTANTE:IL NOME DEL SEGNALIBRO DEVE ESSERE IL TIPO DI CARTA
                pagInizio = Convert.ToInt32(pagNum);
                pagNum = bookMark.Range.Information[WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber].ToString();
                addData( pagInizio, pagNum, bookMark.Name);
                iteration++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ `OrderBy`:

```
var orderedResults = MergeResultDoc.Bookmarks.OrderBy(d => d.Start).ToList();
```

Comment: You need a `.Cast()`; Interop collections are not generic.

Comment: thank's, I think this is better: var orderedResults = MergeResultDoc.Bookmarks.Cast<Bookmark>().OrderBy(d => d.pageNum).ToList();  but I get the following error: 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark' does not contain a definition for 'pagNum', ideas?

Comment: same problem with no definition of pagNum!

Comment: @DenisBokor Doh! Use `Start` instead of `pageNum`. I've updated my answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `bookMark.Start` value. 
This returns the start position of the Bookmark in the document.
So you can run over all Bookmarks and sort them by their start position.

Here is a code to do that:

```
// List to store all bookmarks sorted by position.
List<Bookmark> bmList = new List<Bookmark>();

// Iterate over all the Bookmarks and add them to the list (unordered).
foreach (Bookmark curBookmark in MergeResultDoc.Bookmarks)
{
    bmList.Add(curBookmark);
}

// Sort the List by the Start member of each Bookmark.
// After this line the bmList will be ordered.
bmList.Sort(delegate(Bookmark bm1, Bookmark bm2)
{
    return bm1.Start.CompareTo(bm2.Start);
});
```

Comment: Hy, thank's for your answer, is there some reason why I should prefer this one to gleng's one?

Comment: I'm not familiar with LINQ so I couldn't offer this but I think gleng's (with the correction of replacing `OrderBy` with `Cast`) is more clear and beautiful than mine (still, one line!).

Answer (score 0):

Document.Boomarks should return the bookmarks in alpha sequence.

Document.Content.Bookmarks should return the bookmarks in the sequence they appear in the document. But VBA collection documentation does not typically guarantee a particular sequence for anything, it's safer to read the Start (as suggested by etaiso) and sort using that.